# Exp files and applet dependencies in Java Card

Tags: java, compilation, applet, dependencies, javacard

I wrote in two differents projects Java Card 2.2.2 an applet `Applet1` in a package `firstApplet`  and another applet `Applet2` in a package `secondApplet`.

I want to use some features of the first applet in the second one.

So in `Applet2`, after adding to the second project's Java Build Path the first project, it looks like:

```
package secondApplet;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
...

import firstApplet.Applet1;

public class Applet2 extends Applet {
 ...
}
```

First, with the Java Card tool `converter` I get a `.exp` file using this command:

```
converter -out EXP -exportpath ..\api_export_files -applet AID Applet1 -classdir ..\..\ ... \Applet1\bin firstApplet PID 1.1
```

where `AID` is the applet ID and `PID` the package ID. It gives me a `firstApplet.exp` without error.

The output of this command is:

```
parsing C:\ ... \bin\firstApplet\Applet1.class
converting firstApplet.Applet1
writing C:\ ... \bin\firstApplet\javacard\firstApplet.exp
```

but then, when I try to get the `Applet2`'s CAP file it returns me the error:

```
error : secondApplet.Applet2: class firstApplet.Applet1 not found in export file firstApplet.exp.
```

I don't really get what is going wrong, I thought that the .exp was well generated, am I missing something ?

Comment: Have you put the generated exp file in the correct place when building the Applet2?

Comment: Yes I think it is at its right place because I tried to move it and then I got the error message: `firstApplet.exp not found`

Comment: Did you use `-exportpath` set to `C:\...\bin`? Could you please provide the command for `Applet2` compiling?

Comment: Well I wasn't, but now I've another error. So, my command line to get the CAP file of Applet2 is:
`converter -out CAP -exportpath ..\api_export_files C:\...\bin -applet 0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09:0x00:0x00 Applet2 -classdir ..\..\ ... \Applet2\bin secondApplet 0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08:0x09 1.1` and I get `error: invalid AID -applet`
But I checked, it's the right AID (which is different from Applet1). I suspect it's because I put two arguments to the `-exportpath`options but if I call it twice it erase the previous call... Ty in advance

Comment: Put a semicolon to separate your paths: `-exportpath ..\api_export_files;C:\...\bin`

Comment: TY, but I finally get the error message: `class firstApplet.Applet1 not found in export file firstApplet.exp`:(

Comment: Try verbose mode `-v`, please.

Comment: What happens if you move your `firstApplet.exp` to `api_export_files`?

Comment: After moving `firstApplet.exp`to `api_export_files` I get the same error. Option `-v`shows:
`parsing C:\ ... \secondApplet\Applet2.class`

`converting secondApplet.Applet2`

`parsing C:\ ... \java_card_kit-2_2_2\api_export_files\firstApplet\firstApplet.exp`

Comment: Did you try to put the exp file into 'api_export_files\firstApplet\javacard\firstApplet.exp'?

Comment: Yup I did it, hard to understand what is going wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Over 1,5 years late but nevertheless interesting question. Here's my answer: It is by design. 
If you have applets in your CAP file, your exports will not contain public classes (Specification of Javacard Virtual Machine, version 3.0.1, section 6.12 "Export Component" - last paragraph.) So in order to do what you want to do, you will need to create a library package out of Applet1. In theory, you can do that by *not* specifying applets when creating the CAP file for Applet1. There will be two problems with that: first the converter won't let you create such "ill-formed" files and second you would not be able to instantiate Applet1.

If you simply want Applet2 to be like Applet1 with cherries on top, the best way is to put the machinery of Applet1 into an abstract class -and in a different package-, have Applet1 and Applet2 both extend this abstract class.